# Can't remote access to mysql in Ubutnu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have two virtual machine in VirtualBox with clean installation Ubuntu server.

I need to mysql connect from one to another VM. I allow access from my second VM with ip 192.168.1.80. In first VM in mysql config I write down:

```
bind-address = 192.168.1.80
```

Also tried 0.0.0.0, 192.168.1.118 (ip first VM), comment out line.

I connect from second VM via user = root, therefore I changed host to % in user table in first VM. Then I allowed connect in ufw by different ways:

[image: ufw status]

First VM successfully pings from second. When I try to connect:

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.118 -u root -p
```

I see:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.118' (111)
```

I open ports, allow connect in mysql config. What else should I do?

Comment: Set `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`. If you have `mysql` on both VMs set it on both. Restart `mysql`s. Try to connect. `bind-address` is an IP mysql used to listen on, not the allowed client's IP.

Comment: You need to start the MySQL server first.

Comment: After restarting mysql, run `netstat -patn | grep mysq` to see on which interface mysql is listening on.

Comment: @Kondybas I set in both VM bind-address = 0.0.0.0 nothing changes.

Comment: @ThoriumBR It show: tcp   0   0   127.0.0.1:3306   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   1607/mysqld

Comment: @Michael Hampton Mysql is running.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue this morning - but I'm new to VM Servers + DBs so I didn't try the `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`, I added a new user within mysql with

```
CREATE USER 'name'@'address' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

where the `address` was the IP address of the the client and it worked.

Comment: Answer is correct. You also have to have users configured to specify where they are coming from. Whether that is local host, or 192.168.x.x or % for anywhere